# How can we modify value of const variable?

Tags: c++, constants

The fourth edition of "The Complete Reference C++" reads "A variable of type **const** can be modified by something outside your program. For example, a hardware device may set its value."

What does this mean, and how can it be achieved.

Comment: Could you add more context, maybe the whole paragraph? Is it about `volatile`?

Comment: "A variable of type `*volatile` can be modified by something outside your program.  A variable of type `const` modified by something outside your program will create problems.  Perhaps OP is talking about a _pointer_ to a `const`?  Yet scope is too broad here.

Comment: When you are about to tag your question with `c++` _and_ `c`, stop and wait. This is almost always not what you want due to a long list of reasons. One of them is that `const` has different semantics in C++ compared to C.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of thinking about what `const` means, or stated another way, what *you* mean when you use the `const` qualifier to tell the compiler something about your code.

Definition number one would be, "This variable will *never* change, so it should be placed in read-only memory."

But definition number two is, "I don't intend that my code (or any other code) will modify this variable, so please warn me if I accidentally try to."

So then the question is, what happens if you (accidentally or otherwise) try to change the value of a `const` variable?  And then the question you're asking, how would you even try?

If the `const` variable has in fact been placed in read-only memory then what will happen if you try to modify it is that you'll get some kind of segmentation fault or bus error.  But if it's not in read-only memory (if definition number 2 is operative), and if you try to modify a const variable, you'll succeed.

So then the other question: how could it change?  There are numerous possibilities.

One way is to cheat.  If you write something like

```
const int i = 5;
int *ip = (int *)&i;
*ip = 6;
printf("%d\n", i);
```

there's a decent chance you'll successfully change `i` to 6.  This is undefined behavior, and not guaranteed to work -- you're absolutely not supposed to take a pointer to something that's `const`, use an explicit cast to wash away the constness, and use the resulting pointer to try to change the value.  So it might not work -- or it might.

Another way is to do something behind `const`'s back.  Suppose you write this code:

```
int j = 5;
const int *ip2 = &j;
printf("%d\n", *ip2);
j = 6;
printf("%d\n", *ip2);
```

In this case, what's `const` is what the pointer `ip2` points to.  Here, definition 2 definitely applies: all we're promising to do is not to modify what `ip2` points to.  (But in this case the `const` qualifier isn't going to cause anything to be put into read-only memory, because `ip2` can point anywhere.)  There's nothing wrong with this second scrap of code; there's not even an explicit cast, let alone a sketchy or illegal one.  If we tried to say `*ip2 = 6` the compiler would (properly) complain, but in this case, there's nothing to keep us (or some other scrap of code) from changing `j`, but that does mean that -- surprise, surprise -- the value behind `*ip2` can change.

Another possibility (though this gets slightly sketchy again) is that a global variable is declared `const` in one file and non-const in another.  If in file 1 we have

int g = 5;

and in file 2 we have

extern const int g;

and in file 1 we change `g` from 5 to 6, then in file 2 we may be surprised to see that change when we thought `g` was constant.

Finally, the last possibility I can think of is the rather curious declaration

```
const volatile int x;
```

What does it mean for a variable to be both `const` and `volatile`?  Well, `const` means that this code can't change it, but `volatile` means that it might change for other reasons.  This would be a way to describe a read-only machine register.  This is probably the sort of thing that the book was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If a `const` object contains `mutable` data members, you may modify those safely.  Otherwise, modifying a `const` object after it’s been initialized is **undefined behavior**.  That gives the compiler permission to make your program have arbitrary bugs.  It’s a bad idea and you should never do it.

Now that you’ve been warned, the way to shoot yourself in the foot is with `const_cast`.

It’s likely that the original source was saying that certain kinds of object might be modified by some other hardware or software on your system.  Traditionally, `const volatile` was used to read memory-mapped hardware.  Some device drivers might need to do this.  Modern parallel programs might use atomic variables in shared memory, which a reader thread cannot modify, but which will be modified by another thread or process.

Answer (score 0):

It just explains that the const variable does not have to be placed in the read-only memory. You cant change it (as compiler will show the error), but something possible can.

Your question

> and how can it be achieved.

is wrong because something which potentially can change that value is not under your control. So you can't "achieve" it.

So the `const` value potentially can be changed if it is not placed in the RO memory, and there is something (process or hardware) which can change the memory location occupied  by this variable.

Because you are a very beginner (and at this stage you will not write multi thread programs or device drivers) you may completely ignore this remark.